# How to excute DeepEmailminer app

Tags: java

I have downloaded **DeepEmailMiner-v1-source.zip** from http://sourceforge.net/projects/deepemailminer/files/DeepEmailMiner/Version%20v1/ .

But when I try to execute DeepMailMiner.java in net.sf.deepmailminer package, it showing following error message repeatedly:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.awt.geom.Path2D$Double cannot be cast to java.awt.geom.GeneralPath
    at edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.PluggableRenderer.drawSimpleEdge(PluggableRenderer.java:757)
    at edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.PluggableRenderer.paintEdge(PluggableRenderer.java:663)
    at edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.VisualizationViewer.renderGraph(VisualizationViewer.java:783)
    at edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.VisualizationViewer.paintComponent(VisualizationViewer.java:720)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:567)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:567)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5124)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:278)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1224)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5072)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4882)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:785)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:713)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:693)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:125)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

I have checked in PluggableRenderer.java and VisualizationViewer.java class but did not find any helpful.

I think the problem is in "SampleEmailGraph.java" that is rendered first when we launch "DeepEmailMiner.java" in net.sf.deepmailminer package.

Please help me in figure out and resolve the issue.

Comment: first up - what's there on line # 757 of the `PluggableRenderer.java` file? do you see any **evil** casts there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try contacting the developers.  (The SourceForge project has been inactive since 2006, but you might get lucky.)

Also, try running the application using a Java 1.5 JRE using the downloaded JAR file as per section 3.1 of the manual.  (I know the manual says 1.5 or later, but maybe it only runs with a specific version of Java.  It may also require a specific OS.)

If neither of these works, you may be in for a tough time unless you have the skills to reverse engineer and fix other peoples' Java code.